# How to write pyspark dataframe to different hadoop cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to have a backup of data that I write to a hadoop cluster from pyspark program. Can I do that?

Right now, I'm sourcing a hadoop cluster client profile which sets the Hadoop cluster details in the environment variables. And then I create a spark session to create a dataframe from `RDD`.

```
# write to cluster 1 (current cluster)
df.write.format('csv').save('mydata')
# write to cluster 2 (backup cluster)
df.write.format('csv').save('backup_1/mydata')
```

I know this sounds weird. But is this possible at all? If not, how should I do this

Comment: have you tried file paths with path HDFS name node address
`hdfs://first.cluster.namenode:8020/mydata` and `hdfs://second.cluster.namenode:8020/backup_1/mydata` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here an exemple, why you wont save / store your files (cvs) in parquet format like below :

```
  df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("/backup_1/mydata.parquet")
```

and after use ur spark session perform on it like below :

```
 df_readed = urSparkSession.read.parquet("/backup_1/mydata.parquet")
```

Best regards,

Abakar